# Get data foreach date in from_date - to_date

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have table `absentee_record`

**Dummy record from database**

| id | student_id | note | from_date | to_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Leave | 2021-06-06 | 2021-06-10 |

I want to get `absentee_records` foreach date. Like it will be 5 rows foreach date.

**Controller**

```
$from_date = $request->input('from_date');
$to_date = $request->input('to_date');

$student_ids = [];
foreach($students as $student) {
  $student_ids[] = $student->id;
}

$absentees = AbsenteeRecord::whereIn('student_id', $student_ids)->whereDate('from_date', '>=', $from_date)->whereDate('to_date', '<=', $to_date)->get();
```

```
<table class="table" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($absentees as $absentee)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $absentee->date ?? '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $absentee->student->full_name ?? '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $absentee->note ?? '' }}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Expected Result to be shown in blade file**

| Date | name | note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-06 | John | Leave |
| 2021-06-07 | John | Leave |
| 2021-06-08 | John | Leave |
| 2021-06-09 | John | Leave |
| 2021-06-10 | John | Leave |

Comment: Can you please update the database table records and so us the exact dummy result?

Comment: On the top is database table with dummy record

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please complete the example data in the database. Show us what you expect and what you receive.

Comment: @TohidDadashnezhad I have added my expected result

Comment: What is the actual question? Where are things not working for you? At which point is the code not doing what you expect?

Comment: If from_date and to_date has 5 days difference I want to show 5 rows for that.

Comment: I have dummy data in top table and expected result of that data is in the bottom table

Answer (score 1):

- You can't do that just using SQL because according to your table schema，there is only one row for each student on different days.
- You can use PHP code to build that struct you wanted, like below.

```
@foreach ($absentees as $absentee)
      @if ($absentee->to_date > $absentee->from_date)
          /* some code here to loop date from from_date to to_date */
      @else
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $absentee->date ?? '' }}</td>
            <td>{{ $absentee->student->full_name ?? '' }}</td>
            <td>{{ $absentee->note ?? '' }}</td>
          </tr>
      @endif
    @endforeach
```